# Parsing form data to an object in javascript (Cannot read property 'name' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am following the tutorial on mongodb from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_database.htm). It's just a submit form where a person's name, age and nationality is added to the database. But I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>
> at /home/me/Desktop/nodejs/mongoose-example/index.js:24:18

So it seems like it doesn't want to parse the req.body into personInfo. Here is the program:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_db');

var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        age: Number,
        nationality: String
});
var Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

app.get('/person', function(req, res){
        res.render('person');
});

app.post('/person', function(req, res){
        var personInfo = req.body; // Get the parsed information

        if (!personInfo.name || !personinfo.age || !personInfo.nationality){
                res.render('show_message', {
                        message: "Sorry, you provided wrong info", type: "error"});
        } else {
                var newPerson = new Person({
                        name: personInfo.name,
                        age: personInfo.age,
                        nationality: personInfo.nationality
                });

                newPerson.save(function(err, Person){
                        if(err)
                                res.render('show_message', {message: "Database error", type: "error"});
                        else
                                res.render('show_message', {
                                        message: "New person added", type: "success", person: personInfo});
                });
        }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

And here is the person.pug:

```
html
head
   title Person
   body
       form(action = "/person", method = "POST")
          div
             label(for = "name") Name:
             input(name = "name")
          br
          div
             label(for = "age") Age:
             input(name = "age")
          br
          div
             label(for = "nationality") Nationality:
             input(name = "nationality")
          br
          button(type = "submit") Create new person
```

Comment: Have you made sure there is data in the database and that you are receiving it correctly in the server? Have you logged what req.body contains?

Comment: I don't see any middleware being used in your code. As it says in [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body), `req.body` is `undefined` unless you're using middleware to parse it.

Comment: It did seem to be the missing middleware. Thanks. Also a typo (personinfo should be personInfo)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not parsing the body to JSON format. To parse this you have to include a middleware just before your get and post routes. You can parse body like this:-

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '5mb'})); //for parsing json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true,limit: '5mb' })); //for parsing x-ww-form- 
urlencoded request bodies
```

Hope this helps!